# infinitest usage with Robotium for Android

Tags: android, robotium, infinitest

I cant get infinitest(continuous test runner for TDD) to auto test with android junit test cases. Im using Robotium for UI testing.

Is infinitest compatible with Robotium ?

Here is the Problem page error (within eclipse Problem window) i get even though my test cases run fine when executed manually:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
```

RuntimeException (Stub!) in ProjectTests.   ProjectTests.java
    line 0  Infinitest Test Failure